# how to get the second value of the same class in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to simulate in selenium when two input types are left blank and when the input field gets unfocused it will return an invalid message. What I want to do is get both of this invalid message that has the same ***span classname***.

Here is my python code:

```
    fn_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='fn']")
    fn_input.send_keys('')
    ln_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='ln']")
    ln_input.send_keys('')
    driver.find_element_by_id('submit_search').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    fn_error_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name('formfield__message')
```

Above code works fine for finding the invalid message for ***fn_input***. My question is how do I get the second invalid message for ***ln_input***?

HTML:

```
<div class="formfield formfield--notification formfield--column-view">
  <div class="formfield__label">First name</div>
  <div class="formfield__input-wrapper">
    <input
      name="fn"
      id="fn"
      type="text"
      class="input formfield__input"
      value=""
    /><span
      class="formfield__icon-secondary icon-close icon-color-notification"
    ></span
    ><span class="formfield__message">Invalid field</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div
  class="formfield formfield--notification formfield--column-view capitalized"
>
  <div class="formfield__label">Last Name</div>
  <div class="formfield__input-wrapper">
    <input
      name="ln"
      id="ln"
      type="text"
      class="input formfield__input"
      value=""
    /><span
      class="formfield__icon-secondary icon-close icon-color-notification"
    ></span
    ><span class="formfield__message">Invalid field</span>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="submit_search" type="button" class="button button--primary">
  </i>submit
</button>
```

Comment: Try with `(//input[@name='ln'])[2]` XPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1. Collect your element use list with **`.find_elements_*`**:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('formfield__message')

#for second element
elements[1].text
```

2. Use following xpath with `following-sibling`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="ln"]//following-sibling::span[@class="formfield__message"]')
```

[XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have locators with same name you need to use findelement**s** in selenium

```
List<WebElement> Selects=driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//input[@name='ln']"));
    // if you want select 2 nd element use below line 
    Selects.get(1).click();
```